# How can I get my Unity index, template and build files to generate the game on my website?

Tags: unity-game-engine, github

I am trying to add my Unity Game to my Git Hub site. So far, I can only get the game to work on a local host, as seen in the first screenshot. [image]

In the second screenshot, you can see I have tried creating a repository with the index, build and template files for the game, both with and without a Read Me. [image]

The source is set to Master Branch. The subpage is then published as https://lanninisgarden.github.io/galacticparatrooper/.

Whether or not I include index.html, it directs to an empty page with "3D Game" at the bottom. Am I missing something? [image].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1) Build your unity project for WebGL, preferably not as a ‘development build’. This will produce a directory containing `index.html`, `Build/`, and `TemplateData/`.

Step 2) Commit the `Build/` and `TemplateData/` directories to `/assets/unity/build_name/` in your project (change ‘build_name’ to whatever you want the name of your build to be)

Step 3) Create (or edit) a post and add this snippet to front matter: unity_dir: build_name using your build_name from before. This will tell jekyll where to look for the game files for your post.

```
---
title: "Test Post"
date: 2017-10-13
unity_dir: game_post
categories:
  - General
tags:
  - test
---

This is a test post.
```

Commit this post, then open it in the browser and you’ll see nothing special is happening yet.

Step 4) Next we’ll want to wire up the ‘unity_dir’ variable so jekyll will show the unity game you uploaded. To do this, you’ll need to update the layout used for your posts. If we look in `_config.yml` near the bottom, there is a section called ‘defaults’ where it specifies the default layout for posts, called ‘single’. This is the layout the posts will use, so in `_layouts/single.html` we’ll make the change than handles the unity_dir variable.

Search `_layouts/single.htm`l for a line containing `{{ content }}`, and in the line directly above it, add:

```
{% if page.unity_dir %}
   {% include page__unity.html %}
{% endif %}
```

With this addition, when you open a post with `unity_dir` defined, it will include the html snippet page__unity.html in the body of the post (which we’ll define in the next step).

Step 5) Now we’ll define the html to be included when we’ve added `unity_dir` to a post. We want the included section to load the unity game to be played, just as the `index.html` file produced by your local unity build does. To do this, create a new file in `_includes` called `page__unity.html` and populate it with the following:

```
<script src="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/unity/{{page.unity_dir}}/TemplateData/UnityProgress.js"></script>  
<script src="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/unity/{{page.unity_dir}}/Build/UnityLoader.js"></script>
<script>
  var gameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", "{{ site.baseurl}}/assets/unity/{{page.unity_dir}}/Build/builds.json",{onProgress: UnityProgress});  
</script>
<div class="webgl-content">
  <div id="gameContainer" style="width: 960px; height: 600px"></div>
</div>
```

You’ll note that the variable `unity_dir` is used here to reference 3 files in the `assets/unity/{unity_dir_varaible}` directory– `TemplateData/UnityProgress.js`, `Build/UnityLoader.js`, and Build/builds.json. Another variable, `site.baseurl`, is also used as a part of the path. We’ll set that in the next step.

Step 6) Open `_config.yml` and search for `baseurl`. Update the baseurl variable so that it references your project name. For example:

```
baseurl                  : /minimal-mistakes # the subpath of your site, e.g. "/blog"
```

Step 7) Go to your github pages website and open your post. You should see a game load.

Hope this helps! (slightly edited from: https://ericranstrom.github.io/ericranstrom/general/unity_github_pages/)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand Steps 2-7.

Comment: I got it from: https://ericranstrom.github.io/ericranstrom/general/unity_github_pages/ You May want to check it out to understand it better

Answer (score 0):

I went to simmer.io and it was much easier. Now I can post or embed a link to my game.